# Problem with bash script

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a little problem with a script of mine.
I execute a command in background using sudo and I try to retrieve the PID of the command in a variable.

the code is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo badblocks -o $2 $1 & 

PROCESSID=$(pgrep -P $!)

echo $PROCESSID
```

I executed every command one by one in a shell and it works fine but when i launch the script it doesn't work. I've other command to obtain the PID such as "ps --ppid $! -o pid=" but it doesn't work either.

if you have any idea why?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425754/how-do-i-run-this-sudo-command-inside-a-script

Answer (score 2):

### The Problem

- Using `sudo` inside a script often doesn't do what you expect (see Digital Chris' link: “[How do I run this sudo command inside a script?](https://askubuntu.com/a/425990/175814)”).
- Sending `sudo` to the background will not work (correctly and reliably), if you need to provide a password.

### The Solution

Retrieve the process ID inside the process spawned by `sudo`. If you use `exec`, you don't even need to use `pgrep -P` as a crutch. Create a shell script, say `pid-badblocks.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo $$
exec badblocks -o "$2" "$1"
```

Make it executable and invoke it with:

```sh
sudo ./pid-badblocks.sh <DEVICE> <OUTPUT>
```

This works, because `exec` replaces the current process with `badblocks` (in this case) while keeping the same process ID. We can therefore print the process ID of the shell process before invoking `badblocks`.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing...

If each command works independently, it could be that the PROCESSID assignment happens too quickly.

Try adding 'sleep 3s' after 'sudo ...' and see what happens.