# How do I run commands as a non-root user in a script started with root permissions?

Tags: bash, scripts, sudo

**The problem**
In a bash script, I am using the command...

```
sudo -u node bash
```

.. to switch from root to a non-sudo user, and this is failing.

**The context**
I am writing a `provision.sh` script for Vagrant, to set up a server running Ubuntu 16.04.3 with all the packages required to deliver an app with Meteor 1.6.

One required step is to install `nvm` as a non-root user. After `nvm` is installed, you need to log out and log back in again in order to activate `nvm`. I therefore create a non-sudo user named `meteor`, and want to switch to that when I download and install `nvm`.

Subsequently, I want to switch back to being `root` and log in gain immediately as `meteor`, in order to start using `nvm` to install Node.js.

You'll find a heavily commented script below. Vagrant runs this script each time I call `vagrant reload --provision`.

What command should I be using instead of `sudo -u node bash`?

---

```
echo "# whoami" && whoami && echo "^^^^ root expected"
echo "As root, create non-sudo user meteor:"
pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "password")' $password)
useradd -m -p $pass meteor
echo "User meteor created. ls -al /home/meteor:"
ls -al /home/meteor
echo "Install curl as root:"
apt-get install -y curl
echo "Trying sudo -u meteor bash"
sudo -u meteor bash #### THIS IS THE LINE THAT FAILS ###

echo "$ whoami" && whoami && echo "^^^^^^ meteor expected"
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.6/install.sh | bash
echo "ls -al /home/meteor/.nvm # should be populated"
ls -al /home/meteor/.nvm

echo "ls -al /root/.nvm # should not exist"
ls -al /root/.nvm

echo "command -v nvm will fail silently until we log out and back in again"
#command -v nvm
exit

#### Because the script is still running as root, it halts here ####

echo "# whoami" && whoami && echo "^^^^ should be root"
sudo -u meteor bash
echo "$ whoami" && whoami && echo "^^^^^^ should be meteor"
echo "command -v nvm should work now"
command -v nvm
```

Comment: You'll have to extract the parts into another script and call sudo on that, or call each command with sudo (in this case that's only the bash after the curl). `sudo -u meteor bash` simply starts bash as meteor, it can't simply take over the rest of the script.

Comment: Related, maybe a duplicate? [Best practices on using sudo in a bash script](https://askubuntu.com/q/939583/301745)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you start your script with root permissions but need to run certain commands as a specific non-root user you can use `sudo` with the `-u` option to either run a single command with e.g.

```
sudo -u USERNAME whoami # outputs USERNAME's user name
```

or start a subshell and run your commands in it, e.g.:

```
sudo -u USERNAME bash -c 'whoami;echo $USER' # outputs USERNAME's user name twice
```

The line in your script doesn't fail actually, you just run only `bash` as user `meteor`, and as `bash` has nothing to do it just exits and the original root shell runs the rest of the script. What you actually want to do (I suppose) is:

```bsh
…
echo "Trying sudo -u meteor bash"
sudo -u meteor bash -c '\
  echo "$ whoami" && whoami && echo "^^^^^^ meteor expected"
  curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.6/install.sh |\
  bash
'
echo "ls -al /home/meteor/.nvm # should be populated"
…
```

Another way to achieve the same is a [here document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

```bsh
…
echo "Trying sudo -u meteor bash"
sudo -u meteor bash <<EOF
  echo "$ whoami" && whoami && echo "^^^^^^ meteor expected"
  curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.6/install.sh |\
  bash
EOF
echo "ls -al /home/meteor/.nvm # should be populated"
…
```

Comment: `sudo -u` does affect the environment (i.e. available variables), though. This is important in some cases, for example with `gsettings`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a container environment, the [gosu project](https://github.com/tianon/gosu) could be of interest.  It is intended to solve the issue that su and sudo have very strange and often annoying TTY and signal-forwarding behavior.

A few nice alternatives are mentioned in the gosu project's README.md:

1. `chroot --userspec` may already be installed
2. `su-exec` https://github.com/ncopa/su-exec
3. `setpriv` from the (Debian) util-linux package https://manpages.debian.org/buster/util-linux/setpriv.1.en.html

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/bash
#  (GPL3+) Alberto Salvia Novella (es20490446e)


execute () {
    function="${1}"
    command="${2}"
    error=$(eval "${command}" 2>&1 >"/dev/null")

    if [ ${?} -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "${function}: $error"
        exit 1
    fi
}


executeAsNonAdmin () {
    function="${1}"
    command="${2}"

    eval setPasswordAsker="SUDO_ASKPASS=/usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-askpass"
    run="runuser ${SUDO_USER} --session-command=\"${setPasswordAsker}\" --command=\"${command}\""
    execute "${function}" "${run}"
}


executeAsNonAdmin "" "${@}"
```