# Create a bash alias for several commands, some requiring sudo

Tags: command-line, bash

I know there is lots of information on this around, but I still find it confusing. Please help me with this quick one liner.

What do I need to write and where to make this a permanent feature of my system?

This is the command:

```
sudo apt update &&\
sudo apt upgrade -y &&\
sudo flatpak update &&\
conda upgrade --all -y
```

Maybe call it with `sudo updateall`

*Slight digression:* I asked a question about upgrade appimage and snap a while ago. There exists appimagehub but it pooly supported at the current time and snap by design updates without user involvement and there is no way to change this I believe. The others here can be manually updated.

Comment: I'd store your 'command' in a text file 'updateall' (maybe as a second line with `#!/bin/bash` as the first line). next `chmod a+rx` the file so its executable. finally make it available to anyone & everywhere `sudo ln -s /home/user/updateall /usr/local/bin/updateall` (or somewhere else you want in your $PATH), so anyone can execute it.  it can also be done in other ways eg. your own ~/bin or using alias etc

Comment: Personally, I'd separate the commands. && implies relying on previous commands to work. For apt upgrade and update it makes sense, but doesn't for other two. So `sudo bash -c 'apt update && apt upgrade'` and let other two run by themselves. But that's just my opinion.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To make it available to all users who have sudo privileges(needed for the commands)

`sudo nano /etc/bash.bashrc`

To make it available for your user only `sudo nano /home/yourusername/.bashrc`

Go to the bottom of the file and add your aliases like so, I included the commented out (`#`)ALIAS LIST title

```
#ALIAS LIST

alias updateall='apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo flatpak upgrade && conda upgrade --all -y'

alias sudo='sudo '
```

Save the file, then run `exec bash` from the terminal.

The first alias is your command, the second alias allows you to use `sudo` with aliases.

Comment: No need to alias `sudo `. Simply put sudo into the alias.

Answer (score 4):

In your rc file usually `.bashrc` with `vim ~/.bashrc` or `nano ~/.bashrc` add:

```
makealias() { echo "alias $1"="'${@:2}'" >> ~/.bashrc; }
```

Next time you want to add a bash alias just use:

```
makealias name command
```

Example: `makealias brc vim ~/.bashrc`

**EDIT**

This method does work with `sudo`, `&&`, `||` and other operators like `;` if you enclose them in single quotes when making the alias.

Example: `makealias updateall sudo apt-get update '&&' sudo apt-get upgrade`

Do yourself a favor and use `;` instead of `&&` that is good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file `updateall`, put it on your path `/usr/local/bin` and make it executable.

You can format the file like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo flatpak upgrade
conda upgrade --all -y
```

Then just run the script as `updateall` (without `sudo`)

Comment: I think this is actually a more elegant solution by removing sudo from the script. Except that conda is *not* a sudo command so that doesn't actually work.

Comment: You can allow the `conda` command to be run as a normal user as [terdon explains here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425754/how-do-i-run-a-sudo-command-inside-a-script/425990#425990)

Comment: Answer modified to run all commands except `conda` with sudo.

Comment: `sudo -u $USER conda upgrade --all -y` does the job of running conda without `sudo` privileges.