# Desktop launcher for script in terminal containing sudo command

Tags: bash, scripts, .desktop

I'm trying to write a .desktop file to open a terminal and visualize output from my running program using strace, this is what I did:

**myfile.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Tester        
Comment=Debug
Exec=gksu "gnome-terminal -e \"bash -c '/home/me/Desktop/myscript.sh;$SHELL'\""
Icon=utilities-terminal
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```

**myscript.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

PID=$(pidof mysoftware)

sudo strace -p$PID -s9999 -e write
```

both files having execution permission, clicking on the desktop entry prompt for password, but nothing happens, where am I wrong?
Thank you

Comment: What happens if you set `Terminal=true`?

Comment: terminal appears under the window to input the password this time.. but after clicking ok nothing happen, everything vanish..

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425754/how-do-i-run-a-sudo-command-inside-a-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a Solution:

**myfile.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Tester        
Comment=Debug
Exec=gksu "gnome-terminal -x bash -c /home/me/Desktop/myscript.sh"
Icon=utilities-terminal
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```

**myscript.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

PID=$(pidof mysoftware)

sudo strace -p$PID -s9999 -e write
$SHELL
```