# Why does my bash script output “+ '[' 0 -le 1 ']'” when started with bash -x script.sh?

Tags: bash, scripts

I have created the following shell scrip to backup MySQL DB, zip it, and then copy it to an s3 bucket:

```
#vim /home/ubuntu/backup/mysqlbackup2.sh

#!/bin/bash
## Backup mysql DB, zip it and then copy it to s3 bucket

mysqldump -hhostname -uusername dbName -p'p@ssW0rd' > db.sql

if [ $? -le 1 ] 
then
    # zip the file and copy it s3 bucket
    sudo gzip -9 db.sql
    s3cmd put db.sql.gz s://mys3bucket/
else 
    echo "Fail to backup MySQL DB" >> "backup.log"
fi
```

It does everything fine and the backup is copied to s3 bucket. But I cannot understand the output of shell script:

[image]

I understand the password warning but why does it show: `'[' 0 -le 1 ']'`? Is there anything wrong in my if condition?

Comment: There’s no need to have `sudo` inside the script (and that’s actually not a good practice, see https://askubuntu.com/q/425754/507051) if you run the whole script as root.

Comment: Like @desert said you will need to changer two things in your script those wold be 1) remove "sudo" and 2) make the "-le" option "-lt" and this is what you most likely want.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen: thanks, I have removed sudo. But mysqldump returns 1 (warning), because of using the command line password... I wasn't sure how to get around that.

Comment: That should be coming from the mysqldump line. Run that alone to see what gives.

Comment: OK, I see. I thought $? is getting the exit status of mysqldump. Is that not the case?

Comment: It is, I think you two are misunderstanding each other. See my comment on the answer for an approach to test for 0 or 1 explicitly.

Comment: I changed the condition to `[ $? -eq 0 ]` and it's working. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script:

```
mysqldump -hhostname -uusername dbName -p'p@ssW0rd' > db.sql

if [ $? -lt 1 ] #<-- if the script exit status value is less than or equal 1, which means it succeeded then execute the if block
then
    # zip the file and copy it s3 bucket
    gzip -9 db.sql #<-- create a zipped folder from the mysql backup file
    s3cmd put db.sql.gz s://mys3bucket/ #<-- Amazon http request PUT command
else 
    echo "Fail to backup MySQL DB" >> "backup.log" #<-- if the backup failed let us know by out putting this message into the backup.log file
fi
```

`'[' 0 -le 1 ']'`: A zero here means the the command to backup succeeded, and reads "less than or equal to". And yes those lines with a "+" are showing you the various steps in the execution process and that is because you used the `-x`  in the option in executing the bash script.

Also as noted by desert the sudo and the "-le" option should be removed and changed to "-lt" respectively.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had no idea what the -x is for.

Comment: thanks @dessert will update that wasn't looking!

Comment: wait, but if the exit status is 1, which means `mysqldump` *didn’t* succeed, this will still fire `gzip` etc. – I think they actually *meant* `-lt`, it’s not useful with `-le`.

Comment: @dessert: the exit status of mysql is 1 (warning). That's because I am passing the password in command line... I wasn't sure how to get around that warning.

Comment: In this case I’d use `[[ $? = [01] ]]` or `[[ $? = 0 || $? = 1 ]]`.