# shell script is not executed after adding it as a crontab job

Tags: command-line, bash, cron

I have added the following crontab job:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

[image]

```
58 * * * * ubuntu /home/ubuntu/backup/mysqlbackup.sh
>/home/ubuntu/backup/log/backup.log
```

I have tried both root and ubuntu users.

When I run the command:

```
sudo crontab -l
```

[image]

And when I run:

```
systemctl status cron
```

[image]

But [mysqlbackup.sh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144932/why-does-my-bash-script-output-0-le-1-when-started-with-bash-x-scr) is not executed. Any idea what is the problem or how can I diagnose what is going wrong?

---

*Note I have added only minutes to test the script*

Comment: Add at end of line: `2>&1` This will also redirect stderr to same log file. Then check log for errors.

Comment: To see error messages you can use `journalctl -b | grep -i cron`

Comment: Please don't add screen dumps of text. Copy and paste text and format it corretly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ```
> 58 * * * * ubuntu /home/ubuntu/backup/mysqlbackup.sh >/home/ubuntu/backup/log/backup.log
> ```

This is incorrect format.

The format is described in the crontab file:

```
  # m h  dom mon dow   command
```

`ubuntu` is not a command. Remove it, so the line reads:

```
  58 * * * *  /home/ubuntu/backup/mysqlbackup.sh >/home/ubuntu/backup/log/backup.log
```

Systemwide crontab, specified in `/etc/crontab` has the user field:

> ```
> These files also have username fields,
> # that none of the other crontabs do.
> [...]
> # m h dom mon dow user  command
> ```

Comment: Thanks... should I not add the user?

Comment: No, if you want to run it as a specific user, you should add it to that users crontab, e.g. run `crontab -e` as the user in question. The editor shows you the correct format, complete with examples.

Comment: +1 the *user* field is an **extra** field that is only used in system-wide crontabs (`/etc/crontab` and files in `/etc/cron.d/`)