# How to put sudo operations (apt-get) on a shell script?

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, scripts, sudo

I am doing several operations installing packages etc and one of those are

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
```

obviously it asks my password.

Now, I would like to put all the operations I did in a script so that other people can do it too.

But how do I put this operation in a script if it requires that the user enters the sudo password?

(before in a dockerfile what I did was to mark first the USER as root and RUN the command, but I am not using docker this time)

Comment: FYI: You do realize  `apt-get install` won't work without `sudo`  (*possibly a typo in your question*)

Comment: This isn't elegant and it's not secure, but you can write: echo "your-password" | sudo -S apt-get update && echo "your-password" | sudo -S apt-get upgrade -y && echo "your-password" | sudo -S <any other commands you want to run as SU>        -S with sudo makes it read the password from standard input. I haven't put this an an answer as it means your password is there in plain text in the script, and it'll save your password in the shell history. I don't think that's a great idea - there must be a more secure way (eg password read from a secure file?).

Comment: "the sudo password" ... There isn't a specific "sudo password". Either it's asking for your user's password (the default) or root's password (if you configured `targetpw` or `rootpw`. If they don't have sudo access, put the commands in a script, give them sudo access to that script and tell them to run that script with sudo.

Comment: Please tell us what you exactly trying to accomplish, i.e. why other people need to do that, too? Is it on the same machine or are you sharing that script with i.e. your coworkers?

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425754/how-do-i-run-a-sudo-command-inside-a-script) .

To summerise, you should not be using `sudo` inside a shell script, rather run the whole script with `sudo` privilage.

```
sudo ./script.sh
```

Otherwise, if you still want, you can do,

```
sudo -u username command
```